# AngularJs Divs won't toggle using <select>

Tags: angularjs

I have this in my view:

```
<div>
   <select ng-model="chartType" ng-change="AnalyticsChartTypeChanged(chartType)" 
           ng-init="chartType='Data grid'">
      <option value="Data grid">Data grid</option>
      <option value="Histogram">Histogram</option>
</select>

{{chartType}}
<br>showAnalyticsDataGrid == {{showAnalyticsDataGrid}}
<br>showAnalyticsHistogram == {{showAnalyticsHistogram}}

<div ng-show="{{showAnalyticsDataGrid}}">
   <p>Data grid goes here</p>
</div>

<div ng-show="{{showAnalyticsHistogram}}">
   <p>Histogram goes here</p>
</div>
```

and the ng-chnage funtion is

```
$scope.AnalyticsChartTypeChanged = function(chartType) 
{
    switch (chartType)
    {
        case 'Data grid': $scope.showAnalyticsDataGrid = true; 
                            $scope.showAnalyticsHistogram = false;
                            console.log('Show analytics data grid');
                            break;

        case 'Histogram': $scope.showAnalyticsDataGrid = false; 
                            $scope.showAnalyticsHistogram = true; 
                            console.log('Show analytics histogram');
                            break;

    }
}
```

When I alernately select each of the options, the debug text updates correcrly:

```
Data grid 
showAnalyticsDataGrid == true 
showAnalyticsHistogram == false
```

and

```
Histogram 
showAnalyticsDataGrid == false 
showAnalyticsHistogram == true
```

BUT, it constantly shows the Data grid DIV and never the Historgram DIV.

Obviouly I am making an extermely simple mistake, but I just can't see it :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ng-show, you give it an expression and it evaluates it for you. What you're trying to do here is evaluating the expression by using the double curly braces{{}}, which doesn't make sense. If you simply remove those double curly braces and use the ng-show like this:

```
ng-show="showAnalyticsDataGrid"
```

it will work just fine.

Also, remember that those 2 variables aren't being initialized so when the view loads there will be no div shown by default, but you can fix that with an ng-init.

Here's a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/5248/

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `{{}}` interpolation in `ng-show`. Like many other directives it directly evaluates expressions

Change

```
<div ng-show="{{showAnalyticsHistogram}}">
```

To

```
<div ng-show="showAnalyticsHistogram">
```